# Make Windows Batch command wait for CURL result before proceed

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
    for /R %%f in ("*") do (
       for /F %%I in ('C:\curl\bin\curl -v -L ipinfo.io') do set myip=%%I &
       start.exe -ip %myip%
   )
```

Is it possible to make windows bat to wait for the curl result which in this case (myip), and then pass it to the start.exe as args?
Thanks.

Comment: Your code has a delayed expansion issue, what you need to do is to enable and use it, or instead use the metavariable `%%I` directly.

Comment: is there anyway to keep the command in two line? thanks

Comment: Yes. In fact you can keep it as one line, if you follow the advice in my previous comment. However it's worth mentioning that concatenating lines doesn't speed things up or make the code more robust. In fact it makes it more difficult to understand or maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Thanks to Compo, I am now able to get the ip loaded before the next command.